# How to get a complete list of transactions?

Tags: transactions, json-rpc

listtransactions - 9 provides the latest transactions and actually all =)

How to get all transactions?

Comment: I am confused by your first sentence, could you perhaps clarify your intent?

Answer (score 1):

```
listtransactions "" 9999999999
```

The number at the end is the number of transactions to list. Instead of just 9, if you set a number there larger than the number of transaction (I'm assuming you have less than 9999999999 transactions), you'll get all transactions. Here's the [API documentation](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#listtransactions), for reference:

```
listtransactions [label] [count] [skip]
```

if a `label` name is provided, this will return only incoming transactions paying to addresses with the specified label.

`count` is the number of transactions to return (default 10)

`skip` is the number of transactions to skip (default 0)

For example to list transactions 100 to 120

```
bitcoin-cli listtransactions "*" 20 100
```

Comment: Does this list transactions for all accounts or just the default account?

Comment: Is adding this number 9999999999 is good idea  ? because it may be possible in long run that this number will be small .

Answer (score 0):

To get a complete list of ALL transactions you need to do these 5 steps:

1. Download the full blockchain database (sync your node with network).
2. Download blockchain parser [here](https://github.com/ragestack/blockchain-parser) and open it in text editor.
3. Comment all strings that begins with `resList.append` except `resList.append('TX hash = ' + tmpHex)`
4. Change `dirA` and `dirB` variables to yours directories.
5. Run the script.

So you will get the text files in `dirB` with TX hashes according to your input `blk*****.dat` files from `dirB`. This is the most simple and trustworthy way to extract ALL data from blockchain database. In your case it is transactions hashes.